# Asp.NET C# MVC - How show the result a query with multiples table

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm executing the following code:

```
public ActionResult BranchUser(int ? idBranch)
        {
            CtrForm objCtrForm = new CtrForm();
            objCtrForm.Connect();
            objCtrForm.query.Connection = objCtrForm.connection;
            objCtrForm.query.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            List<tblUser> listBranchUser = new List<tblUser>();
            string sql = @"SELECT B.name, B.phone, B.email, B.idUser FROM tblBranchUser A
                           INNER JOIN tblUsers B ON A.idUser = B.idUser
                           WHERE A.idBranch = " + idBranch;
            objCtrForm.query.CommandText = sql;
            objCtrForm.connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader sReader = objCtrForm.query.ExecuteReader();            
            while (sReader.Read())
            {
                listBranchUser.Add(
                    new tblUser
                    {
                        idUser = Convert.ToInt32(sReader["idUser"]),
                        name = Convert.ToString(sReader["name"]),
                        phone = Convert.ToString(sReader["phone"]),
                        email = Convert.ToString(sReader["email"])
                    }
                    );
            }
            objCtrForm.connection.Close();
            return View(listBranchUser);
        }
```

but I got the following error when I call the function:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '='.'

[image]

I don't understand why I get this, due to I executed in other functions but I only called one table, not two. Any advice I will appreciate.

Comment: idBranch can be null

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Technically, in this case it’s not possible to inject SQL, and yet very possible to form badly generated SQL which leads to the syntax error here. Using parameters is *a uniform practice to avoid cases where real/malicious SQL injection can occur..* and avoid silly programming edge-cases like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe C# won't implicitly convert an integer to a string.

Try replacing

```
string sql = @"SELECT B.name, B.phone, B.email, B.idUser FROM tblBranchUser A
                           INNER JOIN tblUsers B ON A.idUser = B.idUser
                           WHERE A.idBranch = " + idBranch;
```

With

```
string sql = @"SELECT B.name, B.phone, B.email, B.idUser FROM tblBranchUser A
                           INNER JOIN tblUsers B ON A.idUser = B.idUser
                           WHERE A.idBranch = " + idBranch.ToString();
```

Comment: Thk, your advice works. But I got another way to fixed too.
string sql = @"SELECT B.name, B.phone, B.email, B.idUser FROM tblBranchUser A 
                           INNER JOIN tblUsers B ON A.idUser = B.idUser 
                           WHERE A.idBranch = @idBranch";
query.Parameters.Add("@idBranch", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idBranch;